# Continuity, differentiability of $f(x,y)=\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}y^b}{x^2+y^2}$ , $x^2+y^2\ne 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}y^b}{x^2+y^2}&,\text{ when }x^2+y^2\ne 0 \\ 0&,\text{ when }x^2+y^2=0\end{cases}$$
>
> Discuss $f$ ’s continuity, differentiability, partial derivative’s continuity.

**My attempt:**

Let $y=kx$ ,and $x\rightarrow 0$

Then $f=(1+k^2)^{-1}x^{-\frac{1}{2}+b}k^b$ then I guess I should be $>\frac{1}{2}$ and $<$ and $=$

But I don’t know how to proof the continuity ,and differentiability ,and partial derivative’s continuity on the three situation

Comment: "Then I guess I should be > 1/2" is meaningless.  Are we to presume f is a real value function?

Comment: @WilliamElliot yes we assume f is real function

Comment: Then you should restrict the domain of f to nonnegative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\le \frac{1}{2|xy|}$$

Comment: So when b$\ge 1 is continuity ,but when b<1 what should I do

Comment: In this case we have no continuity

Comment: how I proof it I

Comment: In this case $$|f(x,y)|$$ tends not to zero

Comment: but how I proof it I still don’t figure it out ,can you write explicit to me thanks very much